# Управление html - файлами

Tags: delphi, html

У меня есть эл.учебник в HTML. Как сделать приложение в Delphi7, для выбора и загрузки нужного раздела из HTML-структуры. Типа, кнопка1-учебник, кн2-тест, и т.д. и т.п..
Помогите, пожалуйста. Может есть исходник буду признателен!

Answer (score 2):

Что мешает сделать через TWebBrowser. Кидай его на форму, добавляй свои кнопки и на OnClick у кнопок забивай код

```
///Для первой
....
Webbrowser1.Navigate('file:///D:/HTML/1.html');
....
///для второй
...
Webbrowser1.Navigate('file:///D:/HTML/2.html');
...
```

Естественно путь указываете исходя из того на какие странички вам нужно ссылаться и где они у вас лежат. Ну вот ссылка еще [Открытие локальных файлов в TWebBrowser](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/wb_open_local_files.html)